# infinitive verb form + よ

Tags: verbs

What is the effect of putting よ after an infinitive verb form?

Example:

> **世界一のパティシエになりよ!**

Thanks in advance! ありがとうございます！
^^

Comment: Your sentence is very unnatural. Wasn't it なりなよ or なるよ?

Comment: I might attribute it to some dialects if not a typo.

Comment: oops I checked it and it was actually "なれ" instead of "なり" Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally よ is a kind of intensifiers so "a infinitive verb + よ" will strengthen the meaning of the verb.

In your example なる (なり isn't an infinitive though) means "to become", so なるよ! will be "surely become ... !"